# Implement a set using structure but it is giving errors

Tags: c, struct

It is giving error in `pushintoset` function that array undeclared first use in this function
invalid type argument of '->' (have 'int')

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct set
{
    int data1;
    int data2;
    int size;
    int *array;
    int index;
};

struct set *createset(int capacity)
{
    struct set * s = (struct set*)malloc(sizeof(struct set));
     s->size = capacity;
     s->array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * s->size);
    return s;
}

void pushintoset(struct set *st)       //giving error in this function that array undeclared                      
 {   
    int item1; 
    int item2;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("enter set %d \n",i);
        scanf("%d %d",&item1,&item2);
        st->index = i;
        st->array[st->index]->data1 = item1;
        st-array[st->index]->data2 = item2;
        st->array[st->index]->index = i;
    }
}

void printset(struct set * s)
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        printf("%d  \t %d \n",s->array[i]->data1,s->array[i]->data2);
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct set * se = createset(5);
    if(se==NULL)``
    printf("memory not allocate");
    pushintoset(se);
    printset(se);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
st-array[st->index]->data2 = item2; // loss of '>' after 'st-'
```

and you should not access struct member array as a struct point here.

Comment: It's an error, but obviously OP didn't pasted his real code. And anyway this structure doesn't containt such member.

Answer (score 0):

You try to access

```
  st->array[st->index]->data1
```

`st->array[st->index]` is of type `int`, you can't access `->data2`?

---

In your main you instantiate a `strut set` with an internal array size of 5, then you pass it to `pushIntToSet()`, the code should be instead:

```
void pushintoset(struct set *st)                      
{   
  int item1; 
  int item2;
  int i;

  if (set == NULL) //checking for null ptr
    return ;
  printf("Enter two numbers for set [%d] \n", i);
  scanf("%d %d", &item1, &item2);
  st->data1 = item1;
  st->data2 = item2;
}
```

It's probably not what you wanted to do, but the array is just an int array and hae nothing to do with data1/data2.

Comment: If this was the answer you can accept it

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific ?

What are you trying to do in these lines

```
st->array[st->index]->data1 = item1;
st-array[st->index]->data2 = item2;
st->array[st->index]->index = i;
```

st is a pointer to struct set and you can access its variable

```
st-> structure member
```

you can access data1 and data2 this way

```
st->data1 and st->data2
```

Answer (score 0):

`data1` and `data2` is part of set structure. They are not member of `st->array`. `st->array` is  type of `int *`. You should try `st->data1` , `st->data2`.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a single pointer array and instead of storing the values directly you are storing int type.

see the below code it is working fine.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


struct set
{
int data1;
int data2;
int size;
int *array;
int index;
};

struct set *createset(int capacity)
{
 struct set * s = (struct set*)malloc(sizeof(struct set));
 s->size = capacity;
 s->array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * s->size);
 return s;
}


void pushintoset(struct set *st)       //giving error in this function that array undeclared                      
{   
int item1; 
int item2;
int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    printf("enter set %d \n",i);
    scanf("%d %d",&item1,&item2);
    st->index = i;
st->array[st->index] = item1;
st->array[st->index] = item2;
st->array[st->index] = i;
}

}

void printset(struct set * s)
{
int i;
for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
    printf("%d  \t %d \n",s->array[i],s->array[i]);
}

}


int main()
{
struct set * se = createset(5);
if(se==NULL)
printf("memory not allocate");
pushintoset(se);
printset(se);
return 0;
}
```

see it on live here

https://ideone.com/TXBpsP

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the three lines:

```
st->array[st->index]->data1 = item1;
st-array[st->index]->data2 = item2;
st->array[st->index]->index = i;
```

You should spot the misalignment.

```
st - array
```

references the variable `array`, which is not defined.  That's why you're getting the mention of `array` being undefined.  You're missing the `>` necessary to make it compile.

When you fix that, you have a problem that `st->array` is an integer pointer; you're trying to treat it as an array of pointers to your structure type.

Answer (score 0):

```
void pushintoset(struct set *st)       //giving error in this function that array undeclared                      
{   
    int item1; 
    int item2;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("enter set %d \n",i);
        scanf("%d %d",&item1,&item2);
        st->index = i;
        // st->array[st->index] is ok
        // but st->array[st->index]->data1 is wrong
        // array is a pointer of int as your define, 
        // it isn't a strcut, have no member data1 and data2
        // and the other probelm, wild pointer!
        // you use it as a array without initialize it (Memory allocation)
        st->array[st->index]->data1 = item1; // ??
        st-array[st->index]->data2 = item2;
        st->array[st->index]->index = i;
    }

}
```